/dev/mem write problem
AFAIK, the OS doesn't allow an app to access other apps' memory. Each app is in a space called "PCB" and noone can enter that so we have IPC.
So, why can I do cat /dev/urandom > /dev/mem? And more than that, write data on a special process (link).

root can do (almost) anything. The above command will not succeed if run from a normal user. You have to use it with sudo .

@FedKad You mean root can also sniff other program's data from their memory space??

Yes, of course.
